# SBT: How do I get my custom task to appear in the tasks list?

Tags: sbt

If I define a simple task in SBT 0.13 it does not appear in the list when I run `tasks` or even `tasks -v` or `tasks -vv`. I have to run `tasks -vvv` or `tasks -V` to see it, but here it's buried in hundreds of other tasks. My assumption was that my custom project tasks would be the most important!

```
lazy val foo = taskKey[Unit]("Bar.")
foo := {
    println("Hello World!")
}
```

Is there some way I can bump up the importance of my task so that it appears in the top-level tasks list? It would seem important that developers new to the project would be able to see such tasks without too much digging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TaskKey has a rank parameter, add `ATask` after the description.

To add the rank parameter you may need to stop using the `taskKey` macro and instantiate the `TaskKey` class directly. So this (lowercase t):

```
lazy val foo = taskKey[Unit]("Bar.")
```

Becomes this (uppercase T):

```
lazy val foo = TaskKey[Unit]("foo", "Bar.", KeyRanks.ATask)
```

A full list of ranks can be found [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/sxr/sbt/KeyRanks.scala.html).

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me. Anything to keep in mind here?

Comment: tasks in non-default configurations do not ever appear

Comment: Ok, this is what I was missing. thanks! Cool tip, I never notice this detail.